# Linux find files and grep then list by date

Tags: linux, list, find, grep, exec

I'm trying to find files with the name of `formClass.php` that contain a string of **checkCookie** and I want to list the files by date showing the date, size, owner and the group. The files are in my home directory.

I have this working, but it doesn't show date, owner, etc...

```
find /home -name formClass.php -exec grep -l "checkCookie" {} \;
```

I was thinking that I could add "trhg" to the list like this, but it didn't work:

```
find /home -name formClass.php -exec grep -ltrhg "checkCookie" {} \;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `find /home -name formClass.php -print0 |  xargs -0 grep -l --null checkCookie | xargs -0 ls -l`

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -lt `grep -lr --include=formClass.php "checkCookie" *`
```

Take a look at `man ls` for another sorting options.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a few ways to do this. I found this and it worked for me.
find /home -name formClass.php -exec grep -l "checkCookie" {} \; | xargs ls -ltrhg

thank you for the other suggestions.